# Is there random access in C# stacks?

Tags: c#, stack, random-access

I am kind of learning data structures so excuse the newbie question. The thing is, I am using the Stack class in C# and I would like to have random access to elements. I know I can get random access with ElementAt like:

```
Stack<int> mystack = new Stack<int>(4);
...//assume the stack is filled here
int value = mystack.ElementAt(2) // if I wanted element 2
```

But I can only get the value, I cannot modify it. I mean, in a List for example, I can modify a random element as:

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>(4);
mylist[2] = 35;
```

I would like to do the same with a Stack but it has no indexer. Maybe it´s just not possible, if so, I would like to know also the reason. I know one doesn´t normally use stacks when random access is needed but still I needed it while solving a problem. I eventually found a better way but still I want to know.
Finally, about the ElementAt(), it it O(1) or O(N)??

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. In this case, the question about the complexity of `ElementAt` is disjoint from your other question, and thus should go into a separate StackOverflow question. The reason is that you can mark only one answer as accepted, so if your two questions are answered perfectly, but by two different people, you won't be able to mark both answers at a time.

Comment: If you need random access, use a list. The stack class is specially made for it's purpose. Common use does not include random access, push pop and peek is really all it needs. If you need more, build your own class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to do the same with a Stack but it has no indexer. Maybe it´s just not possible, if so, I would like to know also the reason.

No, this is not possible. [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not provide any members that allow for random access (directly to the underlying list data, that is). Likewise, the public interface of `Stack<T>` only ensures that the top of the stack can be modified, not any of the other items - which in turn means that the class does not have to be implemented in a way which would lend itself to random access (e.g. an internal array), but can be implemented in a way where random access would not be very performant (e.g. a linked list). Accordingly, `Stack<T>` deliberately only implements the [`ICollection<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which does not provide any members for random access, as opposed to [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is essentially a collection *with* random access.

The most likely reason is that, as you said:

> one doesn´t normally use stacks when random access is needed

As for your concrete situation:

> but still I needed it while solving a problem

In that case, you apparently do not want a stack (LIFO list), so just use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Finally, about the ElementAt(), it it O(1) or O(N)??

Related to the aforementioned `Stack<T>` type, and without checking the implementation of [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I would assume that `ElementAt` uses the [enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfw8w9at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by the stack and iterates over the elements in the stack till it reaches the specified index, hence in that case it behaves as O(N).

Please note that this does not have to be true in the general case; it is well possible for `ElementAt` to be implemented in a way that first checks whether the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passed to it also implements [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in which case it could use the [indexer defined for that interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), possibly achieving a complexity of O(1) in that case.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. I was actually asking because I assumed the stack was implemented with an internal array, which would make random access easy. But if as you say it´s not, it makes sense that there is not such random access

Comment: @Pedro: It *might* be implemented with an internal array, but the public interface of the class does not require it to be, and so even if it is, that internal implementation might change with every .NET version (or even be different already in [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com)) and hence cannot be relied on.